# How to correctly join two tables that each have Start Date and Stop Date columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql, join

This should be easy, maybe even a duplicate, but neither my brain nor my search engine is being very helpful today.

My problem is as below:

> Given two tables that both have:
>
> 1. A start date
> 2. A stop date
> 3. A property of an employee. Let's say Desk Number in table A and Team in table B
> 4. The employee's unique ID number.
>
> join together the two tables in some honest way such that you only need one start and stop date per row in the resulting table.

Example input and desired output:
Table A:

> | Start Date | Stop Date | ID | Desk Number |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 01/20 | 05/20 | 0100 | 55 |
> | 03/20 | 06/20 | 0100 | 56 |
> | 02/22 | 04/22 | 0200 | 91 |

Table B (notice the overlap in employee 0100's dates):

> | Start Date | Stop Date | ID | Team Number |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 01/20 | 04/20 | 0100 | 2 |
> | 02/20 | 06/20 | 0100 | 3 |
> | 02/22 | 04/22 | 0200 | 8 |

Example output:

> | Start Date | Stop Date | ID | Desk Number | Team Number |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 01/20 | 04/20 | 0100 | 55 | 2 |
> | 02/20 | 05/20 | 0100 | 55 | 3 |
> | 02/20 | 06/20 | 0100 | 56 | 3 |
> | 02/22 | 04/22 | 0200 | 91 | 8 |

I can handle manipulating the resulting dates once the tables are joined correctly, but the join in of itself is causing me issues. I just can't figure out how to make sure that some dates that fall outside of the range don't slip in. My currently solution for the join, which I'm unsure of, was to just join on

```
[Table A].[Start Date] <= [Table B].[Stop Date]
[Table B].[Start Date] <= [Table A].[Stop Date]
```

and then take the max/min date as appropriate (don't worry about that part, I only care about the join), but I very much doubt that the solution could really be that simple.

Comment: If dates are not continuous (i.e. they have only day precision, not (micro)seconds), then this two conditions should be sufficient. For absent intervals you will have no data, because there's no any source of absent rows. You have to generate them by yourself (with help of `union`, for example), or use consecutive intervals with empty values/deleted flag to indicate rows with no attribute's values.

Comment: Is the desired output wrong here...? Why is desk 56 and team 3 between 02/20 and 06/20? Shouldn't the desired output contain team 2 & desk 56 between 03/20 and 04/20 as well as team 3 / desk 56 between 03/20 and 06/20?

Comment: _01/20_ These are not "dates". Beware of over-simplified data and assumptions.

Comment: When working with ranges, be sure you know whether yo are working with inclusive or exclusive end dates. Start date is usually inclusive.  End date may be either - Inclusive, if the end date is the last date in the range, or exclusive if the end date represents the first day when the  desk or team association is no longer active. The difference determines how you treat equality and whether you should use `<=` or `<` in your comparisons.

Comment: ... (Exclusive end dates, while less intuitive to the human reader, works a lot better in computations. Ask yourself: Does today end "today"? At 23:59 today? At 23:59:59.997 today? Or at 00:00:00.000000 tomorrow?  Another question: Is 22 February 09:00 between February 21 and February 22?)

Comment: I usually swap the conditions around on the second half, it seems to make more sense to my brain. Yes, for overlaps you compare each *start* with the other *end*, this means it's a `AND` condition rather than some complex `OR` conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I'm not getting something wrong here, the desired output should be

> | Start Date | Stop Date | ID | Desk Number | Team Number |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 01/20 | 04/20 | 0100 | 55 | 2 |
> | 02/20 | 05/20 | 0100 | 55 | 3 |
> | 03/20 | 04/20 | 0100 | 56 | 2 |
> | 03/20 | 06/20 | 0100 | 56 | 3 |
> | 02/22 | 04/22 | 0200 | 91 | 8 |

Your intuition as to the join is indeed correct, this produces the right result:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN teams.start_date > desks.start_date
         THEN teams.start_date
         ELSE desks.start_date
       END start_date
     , CASE
         WHEN teams.stop_date < desks.stop_date
         THEN teams.stop_date
         ELSE desks.stop_date
       END stop_date
     , desks.id
     , desks.desk_number
     , teams.team_number
  FROM desks
  JOIN teams
    ON desks.start_date < teams.stop_date
   AND teams.start_date < desks.stop_date
   AND teams.id = desks.id
```

[Working demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4e5f47cae1e8afff775bc07858e7c888)